# Efficient Chat Streams

Tags: node.js, chat, server-sent-events

I'm attempting to create an application which will work as a chat app. I'm currently contemplating the best way to do this and I'm thinking of going with a server sent event package such as [the following](https://www.npmjs.org/package/easysse). Every conversation would have an id, and the message would be emitted under the id. For instance

`stream.emit(1512, "Hello")` would send the message and

`stream.on(1512, function(message){console.log(message)})` would print the message. Only the chat members would have the `chatId`.

I was initially thinking of using websockets but I thought that not every user should be receiving data, as chats were private and I didn't want to configure authentication within websockets.

Back to server sent events:

I have a few questions on the topic.

1. Are they efficient and, if not, what would be a more efficient solution
2. Is the method of sending chat through a randomized, hashed, id (such as `309ECC489C12D6EB4CC40F50C902F2B4D`) secure?
3. Would you recommend a different method for sending chat? This is to be implemented as a mobile application where individual users can chat privately with oneanother so, again, security is pretty important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [`client-call`](http://atmospherejs.com/package/client-call) package (disclaimer: I wrote it). It provides a very simple method to run a client-side method from the server code.

Besides this, you can always just put the chat messages to a db collection and remove them after some time.